# What is the correct moment to create dynamodb table on .netcore project

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I'm starting a new API in .Net core. This project is using AWS DynamoDB. I would like this project to take care of the creation of the tables.

What is the best moment to create the table?

I don't need to verify every time I receive a request if I have the table created or not.

Is the startup class the moment I must create the table?

I'm open to doing it out of the project if it is the best approach.

Comment: The common use case is that your app is a data manipulation tool, it reads and updates data, so it shouldn't be the one creating the tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DynamoDB table creation should be part of the deployment of the API. Doing it in code is not a good idea because the table creation can take several minutes.